# when append values to list by input(), I want to prevent appending same values

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

menu = []
input_menu = input("add your menu: ")
menu.append(input_menu)
while len(input_menu) > 0:
    input_menu = input('add more menu(if not, enter): ')
    menu.append(input_menu)
    print(menu)


print("Today's menu:", random.choice(menu))
```

I want to prevent inputting same menu and want to show a message ->print("It's already in the list")

ex) When I input 'chicken', if there is already 'chicken' in the list, show the message and back to input

and is this shortest codes? or can I make this codes shorter?

Comment: Add condition `if input_menu not in menu:` before appending to list.

Comment: Besides, the last `''` also was added to the `menu list` in your code, this will make `radmon.choice` has chance to print empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for items in a list is a O(n) solution (see [@Austin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8472377/austin) comment to your question). Using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) instead will lead to you loosing the order of the inputted menu's. Second drawback, you can not feed a `set` into `random.choice` as `set`'s do not support indexing.

You can however use a set in conjunction with your menu-list and check if the new item is in the set, else add it to your list and set.

That way you get

- menu items ordered in input order
- no duplicates
- O(1) lookups

Drawback: a set uses some memory

---

```
import random

def PrettyPrintMenu(m):
    print("\nMenu", *m, sep="\n  - ")

menu = []

input_menu = input("add your menu: " )
menu.append(input_menu)
unique = {input_menu}    # set of menu items, we check it to avoid dupes
# PrettyPrintMenu(menu)  # uncomment to get a printout here as well

while True:
    input_menu = input('add more menu(if not, enter): ')

    if not input_menu:            # empty strings are Falsy
        break                         # leave while
    if input_menu in unique:
        print("\n'{}' is already on the menu.".format(input_menu))
    else:
        menu.append(input_menu)
        unique.add(input_menu)

    PrettyPrintMenu(menu)

print("\nToday`s menu:", random.choice(menu))
```

Output:

```
add your menu: soup

add more menu(if not, enter): eggs

Menu
  - soup
  - eggs
add more menu(if not, enter): chicken

Menu
  - soup
  - eggs
  - chicken 
add more menu(if not, enter): chicken

'chicken' is already on the menu.

Menu
  - soup
  - eggs
  - chicken 
add more menu(if not, enter): dessert

Menu
  - soup
  - eggs
  - chicken 
  - dessert
add more menu(if not, enter): 

Today`s menu: chicken
```

I added a pretty printer for your menu, leveraging the options of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: Thank you for your kind and specific answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation wasn't the right implementation for your desired output. I modified and fixed your code:

```
import random
menu = []
while True:
    input_menu = input("add your menu(if you are done, press enter):")
    menu.append(input_menu)
    if len(menu) != len(set(menu)):
        menu = list(set(menu))
        print("It's already in the list. Please try again.")
    elif len(input_menu) == 0:
        break
print("Today's menu:", random.choice(menu))
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: you are creating lists, sets, list of sets right and left only to compare and discard. thats highly ineffective.

Comment: @MINSIK Thanks :)